# Kubernetes Private Docker Registry Push Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

So I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster and installed a private Docker registry. Here is my registry controller:

```
---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ReplicationController
  metadata:
    name: registry-master
    labels:
      name: registry-master
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      name: registry-master
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: registry-master
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: registry-master
          image: registry
          ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
          command: ["docker-registry"]
```

And the service:

```
---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: registry-master
    labels:
      name: registry-master
  spec:
    ports:
      # the port that this service should serve on
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
    selector:
      name: registry-master
```

Now I sshed to one of Kubernetes' nodes and built a Ruby app container:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/RichardKnop/sinatra-redis-blog.git
cd sinatra-redis-blog
docker build -t ruby-redis-app
```

When I try to tag it and push it to the registry:

```
docker tag ruby-redis-app registry-master/ruby-redis-app
docker push 10.100.129.115:5000/registry-master/ruby-redis-app
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://10.100.129.115:5000/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://10.100.129.115:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.100.129.115:5000/v2/: read tcp 10.100.129.115:5000: connection reset by peer
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.100.129.115:5000/v1/_ping: read tcp 10.100.129.115:5000: connection reset by peer. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry 10.100.129.115:5000` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/10.100.129.115:5000/ca.crt
```

Any idea how to solve it? I have been struggling with this for several hours.

Richard

Answer (score 1):

if you're using HTTPS, you must have created a self-signed certificate (with your own CA authority) or you have a CA signed certificate.

If so, you need to install this CA cert on the machine you're calling FROM

put your CA cert in

```
/etc/ssl/certs
```

and run

```
update-ca-certificates
```

sometimes I have had to put it also in

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

(in both cases your CA file EXTENSION should be `.pem`

For Docker you may also need to put a file in

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/<--your-site-url--->/ca.crt
```

and the file must be named `ca.crt`
(same file file as the .pem file but named ca.crt)

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar issue and it was related to my registry not supporting https. If your registry does not support https, then you'll have to specify it's an insecure registry to the docker daemon

echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 10.100.129.115:5000"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/docker

And then restart your docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, add this line into your `/etc/default/docker` file.

```
$DOCKER_OPTS=“--insecure-registry xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000”
```

Where the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is your private registry ip.

And then restart your docker client.

```
sudo docker service restart
```